# How can I get the current screen in Java?

Tags: java, swing, screen, jdialog, multiple-monitors

I'm trying open a JDialog in current screen using dual screens. However, the dialog always open in main screen.

To get the screens I'm using this code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] screens = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

I need to know which monitor I'm running the application, and force the dialog to open in current screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the current display with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234476/how-to-detect-the-current-display-with-java)

Comment: Check this elegant answer.... [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

Comment: Hopefully, this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14273836/1057230), might be of some help, on the topic :-)