# Creating frame on current desktop (not where the parent frame is on) java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

On macOS, you can switch desktops, where different windows are on each one. My code creates a window on certain events, and they should appear on the current desktop, and not the one the frame the parent is on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234476/how-to-detect-the-current-display-with-java

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Nice idea, not sure it works for virtual spaces though

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not certain either; that's why I didn't use mjolnir.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 